# OpsCenter: Filtering out nonrelevant discs

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

The "OS: Disk Usage" graph, gets all discs mounted on the server, even the ones that don't matter for a Cassandra monitoring. I want to choose the discs being monitored, and filter them out to only the ones that are used in Cassandra data storage. Is there a way to do this?

This is for OpsCenter 6.0.10.